# Does tortoisegit support git lfs?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-lfs

Does **Tortoisegit** support Git Lfs ?

Comment: What do you mean by "supports"? Right now, there is no GUI support, however, if configured, it is used as on git cli.

Comment: thank you for the replay, We are being pushed to make use of Git LFS asap, but we all use tortoise, and most users don't know git from the terminal. i'm searching for a GUI that support LFS

Comment: I want to know the answer to this too

Comment: @aCuria This is what the upvote button is for. With your vote you can put emphasis on the question, to raise its visibility and likeliness to be answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I use Tortoisegit with LFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57089103/how-should-i-use-tortoisegit-with-lfs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Yes, you can use TortoiseGit with Git LFS w/o problems, however, it needs to be set up using the CLI once (for every client `git lfs install` and repository).

---

The main question is: What do you mean by "supports"?

Up to TortoiseGit version 2.10 there was no GUI support available for Git LFS in TortoiseGit at all. However, that does not mean that you cannot use TortoiseGit with Git LFS. If Git LFS is configured for a repository once (i.e., it is configured what files to keep in LFS using `git lfs track "*.psd"` and `.gitattributes` is tracked in the repository) and the hooks are set up on the client (by issuing `git lfs install` and Git LFS is installed on the client, IIRC it is selected by default in Git for Windows), you can use TortoiseGit with Git LFS w/o problems as no special LFS commands need to be issued. Working with files then works transparently using the normal Git commands.

Starting with TortoiseGit 2.11 there is special support for [LFS file locking](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-lfslocking.html).