# How should I use Tortoisegit with LFS?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-lfs

It seems like tortoise supports LFS but the correct working practice for this seems absent in the documentation. I need to support my team, but never use the tool myself.

What is the **correct** way to use Tortoise with repos configured for LFS?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is only some minor special Git LFS integration in TortoiseGit yet (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2667):

- If you want to clone a repository using LFS, you can enable LFS on clone dialog so that all files are downloaded.
- Starting with TortoiseGit 2.10.2 there is support for Git LFS lock/unlock using the TortoiseGit GUI (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/3183).

Still, if you set it up as for vanilla Git, it will also work with TortoiseGit.

Comment: So I'd need to do a `git lfs install` from within gitbash or somesuch?

Comment: So where does the users .gitconfig live in tortoise world? And is it persistent, or tied to a repo instance? I guess what I'm saying is that I'm not 100% clear how tortoise and git interact within windows!

Comment: You don't need to care for TortoiseGit at all. Just configure vanilla Git.

Comment: @MrTux what about "LFS" checkbox in clone repository dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly enabling lfs in TortoiseGit only seems to be required for older versions of git (lfs).

"Just a note, git-lfs is now bundled directly with the Git for Windows installer starting at version 2.13.0."

Source: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/2972

[image]